Grounding the concept of a Free Vector space of the cartesian product of two vector spaces
$\def\tv{\tilde{v}}$
$\def\tw{\tilde{w}}$
$\def\F{\mathbb{F}}$
In constructing the Tensor Product of two, finite-dimensional, vector spaces $V,W$ over a field $\F$ it is common to start from the Free Vector space (see Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John Lee) ${\cal F}(V \times W)$. Starting with the set $V \times W$ of pairs $(v,w)$ with $v \in V,w \in W$, ${\cal F}(V \times W)$ contains formal linear combinations of elements which are functions $f:V \times W \rightarrow \F$ that are non-zero for only a finite number of elements of $V \times W$. An example of such a function is $\delta_{(v,w)}$ which is equal to $1$ if $x \in V \times W$ is equal to $(v,w)$ and zero otherwise.
We define a subspace $\cal R$ of ${\cal F}(V \times W)$ that is spanned "by all elements of the following forms":
\begin{equation}
(a v ,  w) - a (v,w) \\
(v,a w) - a (v,w) \\
(v+v',w) -  (v,w) - (v',w) \\
(v,w+w') - (v,w) - (v,w')
\end{equation}
where $a  \in \F$.
Question: As defined above, ${\cal F}(V \times W)\backslash {\cal R}$ is finite dimensional. Given ${\sf dim}\,V=2$ and ${\sf dim}\,W=3$ is it possible to construct an example  that shows that this is the case? This example should ideally show how the basis of this finite dimensional vector space is constructed.

For question 1: Well, what do you think? What if $\mathbb{F}$ is finite? What if it is infinite? Can you write down a basis of $\mathcal{F}(V \times W)$? For question 2: Let me cite your definition: "$\mathcal{F}(V \times W)$ contains formal linear combinations of elements [of $V \times W$]." Your transcription into $\delta$-notation is correct, but people often just write them as formal linear combinations, identifying $(v, w)$ with $\delta_{(v, w)}$ notationally. Ad 3: What do you mean by "free vector space"? All vector spaces are free.

Let me say two more things: "$V \times W$ has no algebraic structure" is wrong: $V \times W$ carries the usual product vector space structure, it's just that here we are considering it as a set. Coming back to question 3, I don't think I understand what you're asking: One can show that $\mathcal{F}(V \times W) / \mathcal{R}$ has dimension $\dim V \cdot \dim W$, for instance by constructing a basis. This should all be in Lee. What it means to "construct an example" that shows this is the case is beyond me.

@BenSteffan I cannot see how I can write a basis of ${\cal F}(V \times W)$ when $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite. By "free vector space" I mean, identify $(v,w)$ with $\delta_{(v,w)}$ (btw what do we identify $a(v,w)$ with?) etc. and then show that given the vectors defined by the four equations above, the quotient space is finite dimensional.

Final note, with which I probably should have led (sorry): Please limit yourself to asking one question per question.

If you cannot see how to write down a basis when $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite, what do you think a basis is when $\mathbb{F}$ is finite, say $\mathbb{F}2$? As for $a(v, w)$, you identify it with $a \delta{(v, w)}$.

@BenSteffan, John Lee in pages 308-309, shows that the quotient space contains vectors that have all the properties of the tensor product. There is no discussion about the dimension of the quotient space. An example would start with a basis ${ v_1,v_2}$ for $V$ and ${w_1,w_2,w_3}$ for $W$ and then would show that all vectors in the quotient space can be written in terms of $(v_1,w_1),(v_1,w_2),\ldots,(v_2,w_3)$. By the way, I put three questions because I thought they are all very elementary (for people that have studied this subject at a graduate level).

Does this answer your question 3, then? You've found finite generating set.

@BenSteffan thanks but I cannot see how to prove it

Your comment is correct, you can start with a $2$-element basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ for $V$ and a $3$-element basis $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ for $W$ and from them you can produce a $6$ element basis for $V \otimes W$. Here's some details on how to do that.
It helps to have some notation. Consider $(v,w) \in V \times W$. Let me use slightly alter notation to avoid unruly subscripts, and use $\delta(v,w)$ for the corresponding element of $\mathcal F(V \times W)$. And then let me use $v \otimes w \in V \otimes W$ for the image of $\delta(v,w) \in \mathcal F(V \times W)$ under the quotient map $\mathcal F(V \times W) \mapsto \mathcal F(V \times W)\setminus\mathcal R = V \otimes W$.
So now we can write down the six elements of $V \otimes W$ that form a basis:
$$v_1 \otimes w_1 \quad v_1 \otimes w_2 \quad v_1 \otimes w_3 \quad v_2 \otimes w_1 \quad v_2 \otimes w_2 \quad v_2 \otimes w_3
$$
There's still a lot to prove: these six elements are linearly independent elements of $V \otimes W$ and that they span $V \otimes W$. If you know the tricks, this is all just algebra.
To prove that they span, since we already know that the elements $\delta(v,w)$ span $\mathcal F(V \times W)$, it follows that the elements $v \otimes w$ span $V \otimes W$. So, given $v \in V$ having the form $v = \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i v_i$ and $w \in W$ having the form $w = \sum_{j=1}^3 b_j w_j$, all that's left is to verify the formula
$$(*) \qquad v \otimes w = \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^3 a_i b_j \, v_i \otimes w_j
$$
If you've not seen this kind of calculation before, let me show you one trick. Each element of $\mathcal R$ converts into an identity in $V \otimes W$. For example, $(v+v',w) - (v,w) - (v',w) \in \mathcal R$ converts into the identity $(v + v') \otimes w = v \otimes w + v' \otimes w$. Let's apply this:
$$v \otimes w = (\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i v_i) \otimes (\sum_{j=1}^3 b_j w_j) = (a_1 v_1) \otimes (\sum_{j=1}^3 b_j w_j) + (a_2 v_2) \otimes (\sum_{j=1}^3 b_j w_j)
$$
Perhaps this is enough so that you see how to use other elements of $\mathcal R$ to write down other identities in $V \otimes W$, and use those to prove the identity $(*)$.

Thanks for your detailed reply. I keep faltering on the step where you prove that the quotient space is finite dimensional. I am not a trained mathematician so I have to do things slowly…

Once one completes the calculation I've started, which shows that those six elements span $V \otimes W$, at that point you'll know that the dimension is finite, equal to at most $6$. To obtain the further information that the dimension is equal to exactly $6$, one still has to prove that those six elements are linearly independent.
